# Add links between gray nodes - Directed Graph Editor d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've made use of "Directed Graph Editor" - http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347 for my research project and I've updated it and now it looks like this - http://jsfiddle.net/fb89orLt/2/.

My question is regarding linking 2 gray nodes together by a link. Right now, I'm storing the nodes' & links' information in the following arrays:

```
var words1 = ['Habitat for Humanity', 'Caring', 'Helping', 'People', 'Safety', 'Security', 'Shelter', 'Community', 'Volunteering'];
var sources1 = ['Helping', 'Community', 'Caring', 'Safety', 'Security'];
var targets1 = ['Community', 'Volunteering', 'People', 'Security', 'Shelter'];


var words2 = ['Starbucks', 'Coffee', 'Tea', 'Chai', 'Milk Tea', 'Mocha', 'Drink', 'Smoothy', 'Milk', 'Cappuccino'];
var sources2 = ['Coffee', 'Smoothy', 'Drink', 'Milk Tea', 'Tea'];
var targets2 = ['Milk', 'Drink', 'Mocha', 'Chai', 'Coffee'];
```

I'd passed arrays "words1" & "words2" in the "nodes" object. I'm getting the problem of passing the sources1, targets1, sources2, targets2 array elements to source & target of "links" object. I tried to find index of elements in sources1, targets1 arrays in the nodes object so that I can push them in the links object, but didn't succeed. Right now, I'm hard-coding it this way:

```
links.push({"source": nodes[2], "target": nodes[7], "left": false, "right": false, "colour": "#000", "length": 250});
links.push({"source": nodes[1], "target": nodes[3], "left": false, "right": false, "colour": "#000", "length": 250});
links.push({"source": nodes[7], "target": nodes[8], "left": false, "right": false, "colour": "#000", "length": 250});
links.push({"source": nodes[4], "target": nodes[5], "left": false, "right": false, "colour": "#000", "length": 250});
links.push({"source": nodes[5], "target": nodes[6], "left": false, "right": false, "colour": "#000", "length": 250});


links.push({"source": nodes[10], "target": nodes[17], "left": false, "right": false, "colour": "#000", "length": 250});
links.push({"source": nodes[15], "target": nodes[16], "left": false, "right": false, "colour": "#000", "length": 250});
links.push({"source": nodes[14], "target": nodes[15], "left": false, "right": false, "colour": "#000", "length": 250});
links.push({"source": nodes[12], "target": nodes[13], "left": false, "right": false, "colour": "#000", "length": 250});
links.push({"source": nodes[10], "target": nodes[11], "left": false, "right": false, "colour": "#000", "length": 250});
```

I want to know if there can be a better, efficient and simpler way using arrays and/or objects to do this?

Answer (score 0):

use function to create the link:

```
function createLink(src, tgt){
  var s=nodes.indexOf(src), t=nodes.indexOf(tgt)
  if(s==-1) {alert('unknown source ' + src)}
  if(t==-1) {alert('unknown target ' + tgt)}
  links.push({"source": src, "target": tgt, "left": false, "right": false, "colour": "#000", "length": 250});
}

for(var i=0;i<sources1.length;i++)createLink(sources1[i], targets1[i]);
for(var i=0;i<sources2.length;i++)createLink(sources2[i], targets2[i]);
```

if `indexOf` is undefined, then use polyfill from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: indexOf doesn't work for objects in my opinion. Can anybody post a working code to show me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: @PRANAVDASS use the code snippet instead of manual link creation